# Failed to add permission to a SoftLayer user ID

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

```
curl -D - -X POST -d @permissionSLUser.in.json -o "permissionSLUser.out.json"
"https://someuser:somepassword@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/1234/addPortalPermission.json"
```

**permissionSLUser.in.json** contains:

```
 { "parameters": [ { "key": "T_1" } ] }
```

**permissionSLUser.out.json** contains:

> "error":"You may not add permissions that the parent does not possess
>   to this account.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"

**Update 1**

I am certain that the parent of 1234 has T_1 permission, so I don't understand why I am getting this permission error.

Would anyone have any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please use `“keyname”` instead of `“key”`.

This is a Rest Example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[user_id]/addPortalPermission

Method: POST
```

Json:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "keyName": "TICKET_VIEW"
    }
  ]
}
```

To get all available permissions, please review: [SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission::getAllObjects](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission/getAllObjects)

#### Update 1:

If you want to use [SoftLayer_User_Customer::addBulkPortalPermission](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/addBulkPortalPermission), please try the following REST request:

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[User_Id]/addBulkPortalPermission
```

Method: POST

Json Payload:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    [
      {
        "keyName": "TICKET_VIEW"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Note:** In this case, notice that the configuration has 2 "square bracket": `...": [[{"keyName":...`

I hope them help you.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. If I want to use bulkAddPortalPermission, how does the JSON look like?

Comment: @KelvinHo, I added a Rest example in the answer (section **Update 1**) where you can use [SoftLayer_User_Customer::addBulkPortalPermission](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/addBulkPortalPermission).