# Don't Work SoftLayer_User_Customer::addBulkPortalPermission

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are using SoftLayer_User_Customer::addBulkPortalPermission to add permissions.

> SoftLayer_User_Customer::addBulkPortalPermission(https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/addBulkPortalPermission)

Recently, this api doesn't work.

When we tried to use this api, we got the timeout message.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Until we got the message, we waited +3 minutes

is this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the request and it is working for me, may be the problem is in your environment.

I suggest you to try the request using another rest call environment or another SoftLayer client language such as python to be able to know it the request works.

You can see in the following link how to addBulkPortalPermission to a user customer.

[Failed to add permission to a SoftLayer user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798963/failed-to-add-permission-to-a-softlayer-user-id/35799585#35799585)

You can use the following rest api call to "addBulkPortalPermission" to a user customer.

Method: POST

```
https://username:apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/11111/addBulkPortalPermission
```

Json Payload:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    [
      {
        "keyName": "TICKET_VIEW"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Replace the "username", "apiKey" with your credentials and the user id 11111 with your user id.

Comment: thank you for comment. but softlayer Rest api returns "internal error". just now we tried to check addBulkPortalPermission as you suggest. and we test at other testing environment(Chrome Extension - Postman)

Comment: Test URL(Post Method) and we attach ticket view permission  - https://IBM_ID:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[user_id]/addBulkPortalPermission.json

Comment: Could you post your request again, please, because I can not open the full request to be able to try why you got ¨internal error¨.

Comment: IBM_ID:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[user_id]/addBulkPortalPermission.json

Comment: The problem may be in the structure of the rest api call that you are using. I updated my answer above with a right structure that you can use, because the request that you are using to "addBulkPortalPermission" is working properly.

Comment: If you get the same error , I recommend you submit a ticket and provide the request that you are using. May be the problem could be with your account o your environment.